# java opencv native library and memory limit

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I need to allocate rather large matrix using OpenCV 3.1.0. I'm running following code with -Djava.library.path=$MODULE_DIR$\opencv\310\windows\x64\ -Xmx8g arguments:

```
public class MatTest extends BaseTest {

  static { System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);}

  @Test
  public void tooBig() throws IOException {
    float[] data = new float[13320*67294];
    Mat iMatrix = new Mat(13320, 67294, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    iMatrix.put(0, 0, data); //exception here
  }

  @Test
  public void medium() throws IOException {
    float[] data = new float[13918*13240];
    Mat iMatrix = new Mat(13918, 13240, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    iMatrix.put(0, 0, data);
  }
}
```

The first test works, since the seconds throws (line: **iMatrix.put(0, 0, data)**)

```
java.lang.Exception: unknown exception

  at org.opencv.core.Mat.nPutF(Native Method)
  at org.opencv.core.Mat.put(Mat.java:953)
  at my.app.MatTest.tooBig(MatTest.java:19)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
```

Is it a OpenCV or native library usage limitation? Is there a workaround for such issue?

**Edited:** attached full code and stacktrace

Comment: Which line does the exception occur at?

Comment: Full code & stacktrace attached.

Comment: Ok, the exception still seems to be a Java exception: Introduce a few intermediate size matrices, see from which point it fails (so what is really the limit for the too large), then increase Java memory (xmx) to see if the limit for too large shifts. Then you know if it is Java or OpenCV which is the limiting factor

Comment: It is OpenCV issue. There are some variables of signed int type as a matrix size which was exceeded by my huge array. [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/Mat.cpp#L1841)

Comment: Make it a self answer and I will upvote that: Helpful research:)

Answer (score 2):

It is OpenCV issue. There are some variables of signed int type as a matrix size which was exceeded by my huge array. Check source code: [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/Mat.cpp#L1841). The workaround is to create the list of smaller Mats and join them using vconcat(slices, result) function.